# Work with fpga-zynq repository (deprecated) with the most recent repository of Rocket chip generator

Tags: riscv, rocket-chip

The fpga-zynq repo (https://github.com/ucb-bar/fpga-zynq) has some git submodules. One of them is the Rocket-chip submodule, but that repo of Rocket-chip is out of date, so I tried compiling the rocket with the most recent repo. When I did that, I got a problem, as we can see in the following image:

**[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: firrtl/util/BackendCompilationUtilities$class**

[Image with the error situation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rK3j.png)

Does someone have a solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow these instructions:

```
sudo apt install default-jdk (if you are using ubuntu)
```

or

```
apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

both worked for me

check what JDK version your system is running:

```
javac -version
```

if it is different then JDK 8 you should set it manually:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection      Path                                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

  Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

it worked for me. Good Luck